# Babel not transpiling class (Webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using babel + webpack to transpiled the code.
Some codes are transpiling, as `arrows functions`, however others no, like `classes` that should be transformed.

The following code is not being transpiled:

```
module.exports = class {
  static setMetric(name, value) {;
    if (typeof ga === 'function') {
      ga('set', name, value);
    }
  };
}
```

Follows the webpack config's:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { browsers: ['ie >= 11', 'safari > 9'] } }],
            ],
          },
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
```

The expected result should be: [example on babeljs](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=LYewJgrgNgpgdDAHgBxAJwC4GcAEBeHAYygEMtcBvAKBxywxIwEtC6YMBZdtFgCgDsSwGABocANxJQIMAJQ4KAbhq0cTAGY5eGAJ7IYITQHMS-PAQDk6iP0LMQ_C_OqrVJ3hazsLYwcLGS0nLKrgC-KqHKoUA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.5.4&externalPlugins=)

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. A package in `node_modules` generated the error.
In the `exclude` property I ignored this package, which transformed it.

```
module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /(node_modules(?!\/packageNameToTransform\/)|bower_components)/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { browsers: ['ie >= 11', 'safari > 9'] } }],
            ],
          },
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

**.babelrc** - [unambiguous](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#sourcetype)

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
     "@babel/preset-env",
    ]
 ],
   "sourceType": "unambiguous" // important
 }
```

**webpack**

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: './script.js',
  library: 'test' // of course, it can be a different name
},
```

**script** - For the purpose of the test I added the constructor with the alert

```
module.exports = class {
  constructor() {
    alert('ok')
  }
  static setMetric(name, value) {
    if (typeof ga === 'function') {
      ga('set', name, value);
    }
  };
 }
```

**index.html** - in index.html invoked our test class

```
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<script>
  new test();
</script>
```

Comment: I found my problem, a package on node module, the generated the error.
On exclude I ignored this package, to transform it